# Django-App with Nginx and Gunicorn - Requests get lost?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

in our company we use a timetracking system built with django. It is deployed with Nginx as reverse proxy and Gunicorn to run the python code.
It is basically a simple system with a button to start the attendance and another button to stop. Sometimes users claim that they pressed start or stop, but the system did not process it.
We are now determing if our Gunicorn configuration is not suitable for our use case and requests get lost.

So, my question is:
*Is it possible, that requests get lost when Nginx/Gunicorn is not able to handle the amount of requests?*

**Facts:**

- Worst case amount of about 150 requests at the same time (150 active users of our application, everyone wants to register its stop at the same time. This does acually never happen)
- Gunicorn runs with the default configuration but 3 workers

Any help in this case is appreciated, if you need further information, let me know!

Comment: If a web-server is unable to handle the number of incoming requests for some reason, then the requests will get timed out because the webserver is busy processing existing requests. I don't think lost is good way to define it.

Comment: Nginx is a reverse proxy. It literally just proxies the request to the gunicorn server. Unless you add load balancing logic inside Nginx which is a different case. Did you do load tests on the number of requests your server can handle in a specific amount of time?

Comment: Also, if users are registering then that's an INSERT call to the DB which is really fast for databases like Postgres..

Comment: There are two things you might need to consider here- How many requests your web server can process at a time and how many requests your Database can process at a time. You can optimize the TCP connections between your application and DB by using a persistent connection which will keep the TCP connection open especially if your application is doing a lot of DB calls .

Comment: Hi SDRJ, thank you very much for your considerations! There is no loadbalancing logic of nginx, just the reverse proxy configuration. If the server is not able to handle requests, the enduser should get informed by his webbrowser, right?

Comment: It depends. When a timeout happens, then the client might have to retry the request but I want to mention one thing. Make sure your backend is idempotent which means if the same request is sent to the webserver more than once then there is no side effects. I think with Ajax or like a headless API, you can get a timeout status code which is 408, I believe. In this scenario,you can inform the client to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the ideas from @SDRJ, I could solve this issue on my own.

#### Original server specs

- VM with 2 CPUs
- Nginx as reverse proxy
- Gunicorn running with 3 workers and 1 thread per worker

#### Load test

Although a small amount of requests had a average runtime of 0.05 seconds, a load test reveiled that the server isn't able to process more than 200 requests at a time.
This resulted in Nginx signaling *"Bad Request 502"* for the further requests, an indication that Nginx can't reach Gunicorn anymore.

#### Optimised specs

Changing the configuration of gunicorn to:

- 3 workers with 4 threads

This resulted in much better performance. The server was able to easily handle more than 4000 requests at a time.

#### Conclusion

*Is it possible, that requests get lost when Nginx/Gunicorn is not able to handle the amount of requests?*

Yes, it is. "Lost" might be an unfavorable description, but it can happen that some requests do not get processed.